# Java array of structured variable

Tags: java

I want to make an array of structured variable `Process`. What I have is this for example:

```
int PID[];
int x[];
int y[];
int n; // no. of processes
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 System.out.println("Enter process " + (i+1) "PID=" + PID[i] );
}
```

How to do it in Java? Is it something like this?

```
class Process {
    int PID;
    int x,y;
}
```

I want it in just single `.java` file with my `main` in it.

Comment: *"Is it something like this?"* Yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an array of `Process` an populate it with your data, you can do something like this:

```
int PID[];
int x[];
int y[];
int n; // no. of processes
//code that populates x[], y[] and PID[]
Process[] processes = new Process[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    processes[i] = new Process(x[i], y[i], PID[i]);
}
```

That implies that there is a constructor for `Process` that takes `x`, `y` and the PID:

```
class Process {
    int PID;
    int x,y;

    public Process(int x, int y, int PID) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.PID = PID;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
btw I did this 

    class Process {
     int PID;
     public Process()  {   };
    }
in main.. 
    Process[] p = new Process[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     System.out.println("PID for process " + (i+1) );
     p[i].PID = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());}
</pre>
and I got NullPointerException (sorry for the unformatted comment.. so hard to format the comment)

Comment: @kiddie You should ask another question for this particular error if you cannot solve it on your own.

Answer (score -1):

```
Process[] process = new Process[length];
```

That creates an array of Process with specified length.

Read more about Array's https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted (or the other similar answer), but more explanation and context (in particular, addressing their "I just want one `.java` file with my `main`) would help.